# Get text after certain element (JavaScript or JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could some one give me some guidance on what's the best way to do this.

I'm trying to get all the text which is after ".main"

I know this might be simple, but it's been picking at my brain all day just before Christmas. So i thought instead of stressing myself out, I would look for some guidance.

The example code only brings back the `Text in P tag` but i'd like to bring back `Text not in it's own element` and the `p tag`

```js
console.log($("#container").find(".main").next().text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="main"> WOOP IN MAIN </div>
  Text not in it's own element
  <p> Text in P tag </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the DOM immutable in this case?

Comment: Try `nextSibling` for text after element, instead of `nextElementSibling`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because `Text not in it's own element` is considered a [text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text) node, therefore `next()` will target the `<p/>` tag, being that it's an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). If you were to go native you'd use a combination of [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling), which is agnostic of the two node types and [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling), which as it's method name implies, grabs the next sibling **element**:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');

const txt = [
  main.nextSibling.textContent.trim(),
  main.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim()
];

console.log(txt)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="main"> WOOP IN MAIN </div>
  Text not in it's own element
  <p> Text in P tag </p>
</div>
```

Comment: why are you using `const`? is this some new fashion to dislike `var` now?

Comment: When using `var` you run the risk of unintended hoisting and/or reassignment. On top of this Javascript variables are dynamically typed, which can also lead to unintended behavior. It's best practice to use `const` wherever applicable. No *dislike* towards `var`. Just a matter of keeping code at least predictable.

Comment: @CarlEdwards how would you then adapt this to remove the text?

Comment: @ChrisBeckett What text are you referring to?

Comment: @CarlEdwards `Text not in it's own element
  <p> Text in P tag </p>`

Comment: @CarlEdwards Nevermind i've just done `main.nextSibling.remove()` and it's worked.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett Beat me to it lol.

Comment: And what is the jQuery answer?

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way to achieve this is to `clone()` the container, remove the `.main` element from it, then get the `text()`, like this:

```js
var text = $("#container").clone().find('.main').remove().end().text();
console.log(text.trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="main"> WOOP IN MAIN </div>
  Text not in it's own element
  <p> Text in P tag </p>
</div>
```

You could alternatively recursively traverse through the DOM nodes that follow the `.main` element, but this is much more complicated and gives the same result.

Comment: You gosh dang beat me to it.'

Comment: You genius Rory! :) thank you for helping me out. I was stressing myself out just before Christmas.

Comment: Good solution,  but be aware that when you have content in the container div BEFORE .main it will be shown too. 
@Carl Edwards answer doesn't have this constraint

Comment: @Archer in that case you'll need to use `prevAll()` after selecting `main` and remove those instead.

Comment: @BananasSplitter true, but that solution only ever expects there to be 2 following elements. This will work for an infinite number of following sibling elements or nodes. Either will work, it just depends on the exact situation you have.